# Is it possible to delete undesired identifications in algebraic structures?

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

In algebraic topology, there is a notion of [covering space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space), which essentially "de-identifies" points that look the same but which for certain purposes really shouldn't be considered the same. I was wondering if we can do something like this in algebra. Explicitly, suppose we have an algebraic structure $Y$. Now imagine there is a subalgebra of $Y$ whose points we wish to "de-identify." We decribe this by another algebra $X$ and a homomorphism $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$, and we think of the image of this homomorphism as being the subset of $X$ whose points we wish to de-identify so that $\varphi$ becomes an injection.

We're willing to tolerate further "de-identifications" than just those in the image of $\varphi$, but we want the *minimum* amount of de-identification.

> **General question.** Is there a generally accepted way of "de-identifying" the elements of algebraic structures $X$ on the basis of a homomorphism $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$ so as to make $\varphi$ injective?

Anyway, lets do the obvious thing. Firstly, define that an *enlargement of the domain of $\varphi$* consists of an algebra $\overline{X}$ together with morphisms $X \hookrightarrow \overline{X}$ and $\overline{X} \rightarrow Y$ such that the former is injective and the obvious triangle commutes. Since enlargements of the domain of $\varphi$ form a category in a natural way, we can try looking for terminal objects in the category of enlargements.

> **Specific question.** Let $\mathsf{T}$ denote a Lawvere theory and suppose that $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$ denotes a morphism of $\mathsf{T}$-algebras. Does the category of enlargements of the domain of $\varphi$ always have a terminal object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the specific question is no. For simplicity, we may as well look at the case where $Y$ is the terminal algebra. Then we can forget about $\phi$ and $Y$ entirely and just think about the category of enlargements of $X$. To further simplify matters, we could take $X$ to be initial algebra. Then the category of enlargements of $X$ is just the full subcategory of algebras $\bar{X}$ such that the unique homomorphism $X \to \bar{X}$ is injective.

Consider, for example, commutative rings. Then the category of enlargements of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the category of commutative rings of characteristic $0$. It is easy to see that this category has no terminal object: $\mathbb{Q}$ is in this category, so the terminal object would have to be a non-zero $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $A$; but $\mathbb{Z} [x]$ is also in this category, and there is always more than one homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} [x] \to A$.

Comment: Nice. I'm tempted to green-tick this, but I'll wait first to see if anyone can offer any further information, e.g. "better" ways of de-identifying elements, or conditions under which the desired terminal object exists, etc.

Comment: If all you want to do is to factorise morphisms as monomorphisms followed by epimorphisms, or something like that, then you can look at the cograph factorisation $X \to X + Y \to Y$. The second half is always a split epimorphism, and the first half is a monomorphism in many interesting cases, e.g. in pointed categories.